# Unable to Clone Git Repo With Commit Id

Tags: git, docker, github, docker-compose

This was working for me previously, but it recently stopped.

```
git clone https://<Github id>:<GitHub PAC>@github.com/<org>/<repo>.git#<commit id>
```

If I take off the #, it works.  In addition, is there a way to only clone a subdirectory?  I'm trying to do this all in one line in a Docker Compose build context line without having to write a script that's run in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Commit hash IDs have *never* been supported directly like this by Git. It's possible that some server did something like this, but GitHub never have. It's more likely that whatever you were doing chopped off everything including and after the `#` character.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this syntax works, and from what I know of Git, it probably never has.  The reason is that in a URL, the portion after the hash is a fragment is interpreted locally.  However, Git doesn't strip it off or interpret it, and so it stuffs the pieces of the URL that it appends onto the fragment, which just causes things not to work.

It is possible that you were using an old version of Git which happened to accept the redirect that GitHub did automatically, and that it happened to just clone the right thing, but I'm pretty sure the behavior you requested wasn't implemented.

If you want to clone a specific revision that has a branch pointing to it, you can use `git clone -b`, but this does not work for arbitrary revisions.  You'll need to clone and then check out the revision you want with `git checkout`.  There is no way to clone just a specific directory.

Note also that you should not put credentials into the URL because those get stored in `.git/config`, which means that everybody who gets access to your repository (like everyone with your Docker image) also gets your credentials.  This is probably not what you wanted to do, and even if it is, it's not secure.

Fortunately, you can specify a credential helper to read out of the environment, as [outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment).  You can then pass in the token when invoking Docker and avoid baking the credentials into the image.

Comment: what I actually did was sourced the user's `~/.git-credentials` in the shell and in the Docker Compose use  ${GIT_CREDENTIALS}.  I just expanded the value above.  Also, I added `.git/` to the `.dockerignore` file and I believe it's not in source control.  Is this OK?

Comment: If you do the clone outside of the Dockerfile and you're certain that the `.git` directory is never included, then it's not as bad.  You still should use a credential helper to avoid exposing credentials in the process list and elsewhere in the file system.  It's likely that support for credentials in the URL will go away in a future version of Git.